# Facing a trouble in pagination

Tags: php, pagination, paging

Can anybody tell me whats wrong in this pagination. I am trying to do the pagination after every 10 records but fail. Instead of that I see all the records at the same time rather than in pagination. Where I am wrong here.

View User file

```
<form action="tuser.php" method="GET">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Here You get the Table View of Data</td>    
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Total Number of User"/></td>
</tr>
</form>
```

**Coding file**

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","testsite");

if(!$con)
{
    die("Could not connect: ".mysqli_error());
}

/*  if(!(isset($pagenum)){
$pagenum = 1;
}
*/
$view = $_GET['submit'];
if(isset($_GET['submit']))
{

    $stbl = "SELECT * FROM `register`";
    $ssql = mysqli_query($con,$stbl);// OR die("Query Error: ".mysqli_error());
    $num  = mysqli_num_rows($ssql);

    echo $num;
    $pagerow = 10;

    $total   = ceil($num / $pagerow);

    /*  $pagenum = $total;
    /*  if($pagenum < 1){
    $pagenum = 1;
    }
    else {
    $pagenum = $total;
    }*/

    $max     = 'limit ' .($pagenum - 1) * $pagerow .',' .$pagerow;

    $ussql   = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `register` LIMIT '$max'");

    echo "<table border=5 table style=margin-top: 252px; font-size: larger; font-style: oblique; bgcolor=#05fa8c>
    <tr>
    <td width=10% height= 10%><b>User Name:</b></td>
    <td width=10% height= 10%><b>First Name:</b></td>
    <td width=10% height= 10%><b>Last Name:</b></td>
    <td width=10% height= 10%><b>Password:</b></td>
    <td width=10% height= 10%><b>Email:</b></td>
    <td width=10% height= 10%><b>Role Type:</b></td>
    <td width=10% height= 10%><b>About:</b></td>
    <td width=10% height= 10%><b>Edit<b></td>
    <td width=10% height= 10%><b>Delete</b></td>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($ssql))
    {
        $rid   = $row['id'];
        $uname = $row['username'];
        $fname = $row['firstname'];
        $lname = $row['lastname'];
        $pwd   = $row['password'];
        $emal  = $row['email'];
        $rol   = $row['role'];
        $abt   = $row['profession'];

        echo "<tr>
        <td width=10% height= 10%>$uname</td>
        <td width=10% height= 10%>$fname</td>
        <td width=10% height= 10%>$lname</td>
        <td width=10% height= 10%>$pwd</td>
        <td width=10% height= 10%>$emal</td>
        <td width=10% height= 10%>$rol</td>
        <td width=10% height= 10%>$abt</td>
        <td width=10% height= 10%><a href=edit_records.php?id=$rid>Edit </a></td>
        <td width=10% height= 10%><a href=delete.php?id=$rid>Delete</a></td>
        </tr>";
    }
    echo"</table>";

    echo " --Page $pagenum of $max-- <p>";

    if($pagenum == 1)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=1'> <<-First</a> ";
        echo " ";
        $previous = $pagenum - 1;
        echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$previous'> <-Previous</a> ";
    }

    if($pagenum == $max)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        $next = $pagenum + 1;
        echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$next'>Next -></a> ";
        echo " ";
        echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$max'>Last ->></a> ";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Wrong as what? It does error?

Comment: Not any error but all the record show in one page. and some time I face Undefined index: submit error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this..........Simple Pagination**

```
     <html>
        <head>
        <style>
        #content
        {
        width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
        .page
        {
        float: right;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        }
        .page li
        {
        list-style: none;
        display:inline-block;
        }
        .page li a, .current
        {
        display: block;
        padding: 5px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #8A8A8A;
        }
        .current
        {
        font-weight:bold;
        color: #000;
        }
        .button
        {
        padding: 5px 15px;
        text-decoration: none;
        background: #333;
        color: #F3F3F3;
        font-size: 13PX;
        border-radius: 2PX;
        margin: 0 4PX;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div id="content">
        <?php
        $query1=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        mysql_select_db("contractor_leads",$query1);

        $start=0;
        $limit=5;

        if(isset($_GET['id']))
        {
        $id=$_GET['id'];
        $start=($id-1)*$limit;
        }
else
{
$id=1;
}

        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  category2 LIMIT $start, $limit");
        ?>
        <table border="1">
        <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
                                                    <th>Device Id</th>
                                                    <th>Puppy Count</th>

        </tr>
        <?php
        while($query2=mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
        echo "<tr><td>".$query2['parent_child_name']."</td>
        <td>".$query2['parent_child_name']."</td>
        <td>".$query2['parent_child_name']."</td>
        </tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        $rows=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  category2"));
        $total=ceil($rows/$limit);

        if($id>1)
        {
        echo "<a href='?id=".($id-1)."' class='button'>PREVIOUS</a>";
        }
        if($id!=$total)
        {
        echo "<a href='?id=".($id+1)."' class='button'>NEXT</a>";
        }

        echo "<ul class='page'>";
        for($i=1;$i<=$total;$i++)
        {
        if($i==$id) { echo "<li class='current'>".$i."</li>"; }

        else { echo "<li><a href='?id=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>"; }
        }
        echo "</ul>";

        ?>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: undefined id error but i appy all thevariable and other properly.